# O que é DTD (Document Type Definition)?

Tags: terminologia, dtd

Como essa tecnologia funciona e como ela se relaciona com outras tecnologias usadas atualmente, como DOM, Xpath e Xquery?

Não busco algo totalmente minucioso, uma visão geral, o modo de funcionamento para a criação de um DTD, e sua relação com outras tecnologias podem ser exemplificadas com HTML ou XML.

Comment: Achei dois links sobre o assunto... [Tutorials Point](http://dev.tutorialspoint.com/dtd/index.htm) e [Edu Tech](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/DTD_tutorial)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Uma definição de tipo de documento (inglês: document type definition, DTD) é um conjunto de declarações de marcação que definem um tipo de documento para uma linguagem de marcação da família da SGML (SGML, XML, HTML).

(Fonte: [Wikepedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Tipo_de_Documento))

Ou seja, informa ao documento quais regras os [user agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) devem seguir, e o que não é permitido em uma determinada versão de um XML. Seria uma forma de dizer a eles, quais são as regras que o documente pretende seguir e quais as regras que o browser deve utilizar ao analisar (parsing) o documento. Por esse motivo, 
a escolha do `doctype` influencia no tipo de marcação que você vai utilizar.

Um exemplo simples de uma DTO usada para definir um animal:

```
<!DOCTYPE animal [
   <!ENTITY header "Detalhe do animal">
   <!ELEMENT especie (#PCDATA)>
   <!ATTLIST tipoLocomocao (quadrupede | bipede) #required>
   <!ELEMENT alimentacao (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

Nesse exemplo, primeiro foi definido o cabeçalho do item como `Detalhe do animal`. O tipo de dados `#PCDATA` significa que pode ser qualquer valor de texto.  Já `ATTLIST` fornece opções para um elemento específico. No caso, o tipo de locomoção dos animais se é quadrúpede ou bípede.

Esse é um DTD básico que usa apenas alguns tipos de dados. As definições de tipo de documento usadas para grandes bancos de dados XML podem ter milhares de linhas e podem incluir muitos outros tipos de dados. Felizmente, DTDs pode ser facilmente modificado em um editor de texto sempre que as alterações precisam ser feitas.

Se quiser saber mais, nesse [site](http://revolucao.etc.br/archives/doctype-dtd-document-type-definition/), que usei como referência, está muito bem explicado.

Answer (score 0):

Este artigo do W3Schools é bastante elucidativo nesse sentido:

[What is a DTD?](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_intro.asp)

> What is a DTD?
> A DTD is a Document Type Definition.
>
> A DTD defines the structure and the legal elements and attributes of an XML document.
>
> Why Use a DTD?
> With a DTD, independent groups of people can agree on a standard DTD for interchanging data.
>
> An application can use a DTD to verify that XML data is valid.

Pode ser utilizado caso os seus XML tenham conjuntos de padrões específicos dos seus negócios ou serviços.

Espero ter ajudado, abraços!

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! Vou alterar a resposta agora e incluir mais informações

Comment: Oi seja bem-vindo(a), obrigado pela atenção, gostaria se possível, focasse sua resposta, nas perguntas do corpo do post, o título é mais uma referência a tecnologia a qual gostaria de entender, o funcionamento, sintaxe e se hj em dia ele é usada e pra que, esse tipo de coisa uma pouco mais abaixo da superfície...

Comment: @Samamba oi, editei minha pergunta, afim de torná-la mais objetiva... O link que postastes responde uma parte de minha dúvida, ainda assim careço de informações para fazer a ligação com as outras tecnologias citadas...

Answer (score 0):

A grosso modo e informalmente, um DTD é um "esquema" para uma classe de documentos XML. Ao se usar um parser XML com validação e informando o DTD ao parser, ele pode então aceitar um documento XML como válido ou recusar como inválido, de acordo com o DTD informado.

Não sei se DTDs são ainda usados, ou se seu uso é aceitável ou encorajado, pois posteriormente foi criada a especificação RELAX NG, que é uma linguagem de esquema "real" (embora simples) para XML.

Comment: Não creio ser informal...