# Existe um padrão para estruturar um site em HTML?

Tags: html, css, footer

Estou criando um site e tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<body>
<div class="container">

    <?php require_once('includes/header.php'); ?>
    <?php require_once('includes/main.php'); ?>


</div>
<?php require_once('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Está funcionando normal, mas eu não sei se estou fazendo da forma correta, o rodapé está fora da div container, se eu coloco ele dentro dela ele não fica na parte debaixo do site. gostaria de saber dos que conhecem bem o desenvolvimento de sites qual a melhor estrutura para o desenvolvimento de sites.

Comment: Depende dos requisitos da sua aplicação, isto é, varia muito conforme seu objetivo. Por exemplo, considerando que a classe `container` vem do **Bootstrap CSS**, ela possui uma largura definida conforme o tamanho da tela. Se você precisar de rodapé com 100% da largura da tela, precisa tê-lo fora da `div`. As vezes é interessante deixá-la dentro. Depende muito.

Comment: É puro, não tem framework.

Comment: Olha é provável que esteja fora do escopo, da forma que está, talvez se alterasse para "existe um padrão blablabla" , mas não sei deixa a comunidade avaliar... Dá uma olhada neste link https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_structural_elements ... A estrutura dos elementos está ligada a árvore DOM que os browsers montam, agora o posicionamento é relativo ao css, você pode ter 2 tipos de estrutura, com o mesmo visual ajustado pelo css... agora se não me engano és esperada uma certa estrutura exemplo, semanticamente  `header` deveria na minha opinião vir antes de `container`, o `main` ...

Comment: Mesmo assim. Não existe uma maneira **correta** de se fazer. Sua pergunta é demasiadamente ampla.

Comment: deveria ser o `container` e depois o `footer`, tudo dentro do `body`...

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss acho que vc se expressou mal, creio que pode haver várias maneiras corretas...

Comment: Anderson, o problema é que eu não sei qual é a melhor forma de fazer, segundo a forma mais próxima de um padrão.;..

Comment: @MagicHat, sim, teria sido melhor destacar o "uma" ao invés do "correta", mas o que quis dizer é exatamente isso: não existe apenas uma forma de se fazer ou uma que seja imperativamente correta.

Comment: Pode existir mais de um footer por seção e pode ter ordem diferente sim @MagicHat ... essa pergunta é totalmente opinativa.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, em nenhum momento eu disse que não era(ainda falei sobre isso no meu 1º comentário), mas de qualquer forma existe um padrão, convenção sei lá o nome, e o mais importante os validadores... E ainda em minha resposta abordei seu ponto de vista através da singularidade...(sempre quis usar essa palavra, heuheu),,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A estrutura recomendada para uma página em HTML5 no seu caso poderia ser assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>título da página</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>menu principal</nav>
    <header>
       <?php require_once('includes/header.php'); ?>
    </header>
    <main>
      <?php require_once('includes/main.php'); ?>
    </main>
    <footer>
       <?php require_once('includes/footer.php'); ?>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

A tag "NAV" pode ficar dentro de "HEADER" se preferir. Assim seu código será mais semântico e usando as tags do html5 facilita a indexação pelos mecanismos de busca. Em relação ao rodapé, existem várias formas de manter ele fixado na base da janela, [veja aqui 5 formas de fazer isso.](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)

Answer (score 3):

A estrutura padrão para um documento `html` é a seguinte :

```
<!DOCTYPE><!--Document Type Definition-->
<html>
    <head>Meta dados</head>
    <body>Conteúdo</body>
</html>
```

[Fonte](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=0d3SFEce-EAC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=html%20structure%20pattern&source=bl&ots=CVA_ySxgUK&sig=7UQ0QeYK_7wvu28H5MDl_n-LOSU&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2m4DJqZLSAhXCFZAKHXiRC2kQ6AEIbjAN)

Agora, dentro do `body` você pode montar vários tipo de layout... Onde acredito (não tenho fontes) que existe uma sequencia, sendo `header`,`content`,`footer`, mas isso pode variar muito dependendo do [DTD](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170537/o-que-%C3%A9-dtd-document-type-definition) e outros detalhes que tornam cada propósito singular...

De qualquer forma você pode usar um dos muitos validadores, por exemplo : [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/)

E [aqui](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html) você pode ver informações sobre o padrão global.