# Por que precisa fechar a tag script?

Tags: script, html-tags

Porque abrir somente uma tag `<script>` não funciona corretamente? Sei que não é a mesma coisa que as *StyleSheets* do *CSS*:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Mas por que é necessário que seja aberto e fechado a tag `<script>`, sendo que não informo nada dentro da tag? Isso não é errado? Ou existe alguma situação em que eu passo alguma informação para tag  ?

`<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> // Sucesso`

`<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"> // Erro`

Comment: Em casos nos quais toda a informação está presente nos atributos, como no seu exemplo com **link**, basta fechar a tag com  **/>**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que define os requerimentos a sintaxe do documento é chamado "DTD - [Document Type Definition](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170537/o-que-%C3%A9-dtd-document-type-definition) "

Em sua [especificação(18.2.1 The SCRIPT element)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) contém essa definição de forma clara :

> Start tag: required, End tag: required

Answer (score 2):

Basta olhar a definição da tag para entender.

O seu exemplo usa `src` para carregar um script externo, mas se colocar o código entre as tags, também funciona. [Veja a referencia aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Este é um exemplo:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
</script>
```